# Json-schema field is present and has value

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a schema like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",  
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "enum": [
        "foo1",
        "foo2"
      ]
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "number"
    },
}
```

I want bar to be required if foo is present and if it has value "foo1", otherwise it should be forbidden. I was trying something like:

```
"if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "const": "foo1"
      }
    }
  },
  "then": {
    "required": [
      "bar"
    ]
  },
  "else": {
    "not": {
      "required": [
        "bar"
      ]
    }
  }
```

However, what happens is if foo is not present, then bar is required and I don't want that. It's as if absence of the field is interpreted as true by the if statement. Is there a way to make one field required only if another optional field is present and has specific value? Something like:

```
"if": {
  allOf: [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": {
          "const": "foo1"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "contains": "foo"
    }
  ]
}
"then": {
  "required": [
    "bar"
  ]
},
"else": {
  "not": {
    "required": [
      "bar"
    ]
  }
}
```

By the way I've found many similar questions here, but none where foo is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values of the `if/then/else` keywords are schemas themselves.
What happens if you take the schema value of your `if` keyword on its own?

What you'll find is, it will validate an empty object successfully without error.

`properties` only applies subschemas to instance locations where the keys match. If your object has no `foo` property, you're not doing any validation on the object.

You need to add `required` to your if statement for this to work how you expect.

```
"if": {
    "properties": {
      "foo": {
        "const": "foo1"
      }
    },
    "required": ["foo"]
  }
```

See it in action here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/L0rlG

Comment: I've tried numerous variations to this, but somehow not this exact one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After few more hours I came up with a solution, which I'm going to post here, because it works for earlier versions of json schema, where if/then/else are not available, so someone might need it if they are unable to upgrade, but I accepted Relequestual's answer, because his solution is more elegant for those who have latest version at their disposal

```
"oneOf":
  [
    {
      "not": {"required": ["foo", "bar"]}
    },
    {
      "required": ["foo"],
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "properties":{
            "foo":{"enum": ["foo1"]}
          },
          "required": ["bar"]
        },
        {
          "properties":{
            "foo": {"not": {"enum": ["foo1"]}}
          },
          "not": {"required": ["bar"]}
        }
      ]}
  ]
```